# Azure Function Unit Test Credentials

Tags: unit-testing, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I have a simple Azure Functions app in Visual Studio. I am attempting to unit test a create game function which should save data locally.

I'm trying to run the function `CreateGameTest` as a test in Visual Studio and I receive the following output

```
[31/10/2017 10:36:46 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[31/10/2017 10:36:47 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.2509695]   Starting:    LemonadeGame.Test
[31/10/2017 10:36:47 Error] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7378276]     LemonadeGame.Test.CreateGameTest.TestDoesCreateGame [FAIL]
[31/10/2017 10:36:47 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7392995]       System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot find account information inside Uri 'http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1'
[31/10/2017 10:36:47 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7403799]       Stack Trace:
[31/10/2017 10:36:47 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7408970]            at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.NavigationHelper.GetContainerNameFromContainerAddress(Uri uri, Nullable`1 usePathStyleUris)
[31/10/2017 10:36:47 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7413043]            at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.ParseQueryAndVerify(StorageUri address, StorageCredentials credentials)
[31/10/2017 10:36:47 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7418036]            at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable..ctor(StorageUri tableAddress, StorageCredentials credentials)
[31/10/2017 10:36:47 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7421637]         C:\Users\Ben Helstrip\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\azure-server-lemonade-game\LemonadeGame\LemonadeGame.Test\CreateGameTest.cs(46,0): at LemonadeGame.Test.CreateGameTest.TestDoesCreateGame()
[31/10/2017 10:36:47 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7505642]   Finished:    LemonadeGame.Test
[31/10/2017 10:36:47 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:00.7973298) ==========
```

From this it appears that I am missing some account information to run this locally, although I am specifying the `devstoreaccount` account name and `Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==` account key used for local development.

Is there anything additional I must include to run this test?

**My Unit Test**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Results;
using LemonadeGame.Models;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Should.Fluent;
using Xunit;

namespace LemonadeGame.Test
{
    public class CreateGameTest
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var game = new Game
            {
                GameName = "Ben.Helstrip",
                NumberOfPlayers = 5,
                AutoNextRound = false,
                PartitionKey = "game",
                Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now
            };
        }
        [Fact]
        public void TestDoesCreateGame()
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Content = new StringContent("{'name': 'Bill'}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
            };
            request.SetConfiguration(new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration());
            var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("devstoreaccount1", "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==");
            var storageUri = new StorageUri(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1"));
            var game = new Game
            {
                GameName = "Ben",
                NumberOfPlayers = 5,
                AutoNextRound = false,
                PartitionKey = "game",
                Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now
            };

            var result = FunctionCreateGame.Run(game, new CloudTable(storageUri, storageCredentials),  new FakeTraceWriter());
            result.StatusCode.Should().Equal(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume give the loop back address you are looking to use with the Azure Storage Emulator. Have you verified it is working and accepts initializing with these settings outside this test? Appears to be where error is generated

Answer (score 0):

the `Uri` passed to `CloudTable` ctor needs to be that of a table, not the base `Uri` of your storage account.

See [CloudTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_CloudTable__ctor_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_StorageUri_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Auth_StorageCredentials_) docs there. Also this article talks about how to use the storage emulator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator